# Dynamic classname styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to write dynamically classnames so that my form will be styled differently when receives different prop values.
So this is my code and what I tried so far:

```
import styles from './styles.module.scss';

  const Component = ({ type, list }) => {
    const getStyle = (type) => { 
      let style;
      if (type === 'STYLE1'){
       style = 'version1';
     } else if(type === 'STYLE2'){
       style = 'version2'
     }
      return styles[style];
     };
      return (
    { list.map((q) => (
    <div 
      className={`${getStyle(type)}_text__container`}
    />
    <div className={`${getStyle(type)}_model`} />
    return (...)
  )
)}
```

When I receive type prop with value STYLE1 I want to be applied version1_text_container classname. This doesn't work, when I inspect element in browser, I see that the classname looks like this:
`styles-module__version1--10lor_text__container`
So the style it's not applied, I don't get why it's that `--10lor` between version1 and text__container.
Maybe someone here can give me some help with this one.. or how to solve this problem in another way..
Maybe I can use classnames npm package instead to solve this problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are getting the `--10lor` because you are using css-modules. If your app was bootstrapped with CRA and you haven't rewired your webpack configuration your 'problem' should be fixed just renaming your scss file to `styles.scss`

Comment: I tried this and I receive styles__version1--3WKmK_text__container.. still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`return styles[style];` should be `return style;`

Comment: I tried this, it receives ```version1_text__container``` which is fine, but it's not working because It has to be from imported styles.. how can I do this to work? If it's not assigned dinamically, the classname looks like this ```className={styles.version1_text__container}```